# Docker Debian Time Is Incorrect

Tags: debian, docker

Running a debian:jessie docker instance on my Mac OS X.  The debian docker date is incorrect. eg

```
oot@134663e76fba:/opt/phabricator# date
Mon Nov 24 15:51:24 UTC 2014
```

but on my Mac

```
$ date -u
Tue Nov 25 16:36:11 UTC 2014
```

What causes this and what's the best fix?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See the issue [Issue 69](https://github.com/boot2docker/boot2docker/issues/69). Basically the boot2 docker vm does not handle mac sleep wake cycle properly. You need to restart the VM. `boot2docker restart` should do the trick. Note you may still have to mess around with time-zones.