# How to set docker container time in Docker for Windows

Tags: docker, docker-for-windows, docker-desktop

Is it possible to set date and timezone in an ubuntu container on **Docker Desktop for Windows**?
Currently the date is a day+ behind my Windows host.

Comment: Try restarting the virtual machine, from the answer to:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27132210/docker-debian-time-is-incorrect

Comment: Time is not namespaced in the Linux kernel, so the only way to change it is on the container host (a VM within docker desktop), or with a privileged container that has access to the host. By default, docker removes capabilities from root inside of the container that would allow modification of the host.

Answer (score 1):

Try restarting boot2docker vm, from the answer to: [Docker Debian Time Is Incorrect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27132210/docker-debian-time-is-incorrect) (same problem on MacOS)

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
date -s "6 SEP 2016 16:07:00"
```

ran as root, obviously change the time to suit you.

Comment: That isn't permitted


root@cca3c7b8dad8:/# date -s "6 SEP 2016 11:09:00
date: cannot set date: Operation not permitted
Tue Sep  6 11:09:00 EDT 2016

Comment: I still get the same thing.

Comment: I needed to set the container settings to `Privileged Mode`